# Access scope variable inside script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

I have one question regarding angularjs.

I have my HTML like this:

```
<html>
    <body ng-controller="datafileController">
        <div class="container">
            <center><h1>Datafiles</h1></center>
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="i in datafile.items">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <p>Total MB: {{i.total_mb}}</p>
                    <p>Used MB: {{i.used_mb}}</p>
                    <p>Free MB: {{i.free_mb}}</p>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div id="myDiv"></div>
                    <script>
                        var data = [{
                            values: [{{i.used_mb}}, {{i.free_mb}}],
                        labels: ['Free MB', 'Used MB'],
                            type: 'pie'
                        }];
                        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my controller like this:

```
aebdApp.controller('datafileController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8083/json/datafiles.json').
     then(function(response) {
        $scope.datafile = response.data;
    }); 
});
```

How can I in data var access i variable? This:

```
values: [{{i.used_mb}}, {{i.free_mb}}],
```

What I want is design a graph using Plotly for each i in items. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's not possible, you need to put that logic in your javascript file.  Basically, just after retrieve the response from `$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8083/json/datafiles.json')`

Comment: Can you help me? How can I do that? Just started working with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

**This is my approach for doing that:**

```
<html>
<body ng-controller="datafileController">
<div class="container">
    <center><h1>Datafiles</h1></center>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="i in datafile.items">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <p>Total MB: {{i.total_mb}}</p>
            <p>Used MB: {{i.used_mb}}</p>
            <p>Free MB: {{i.free_mb}}</p>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="myDiv_{{$index}}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    aebdApp.controller('datafileController', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8083/json/datafiles.json').then(function (response) {
            $scope.datafile = response.data;

            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.datafile.forEach(function (i, index) {
                    var data = [{
                        values: [i.used_mb, i.free_mb],
                        labels: ['Free MB', 'Used MB'],
                        type: 'pie'
                    }];

                    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv_' + index, data);
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, using the implicit `$index` variable and using `$timeout` injected function.  I'm not sure whether $timeout function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid putting code that manipulates DOM in controllers. Instead create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
app.directive("plotly", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.plotly, function(i) {
            if (i) {
                 var data = [{
                     values: [{{i.used_mb}}, {{i.free_mb}}],
                     labels: ['Free MB', 'Used MB'],
                     type: 'pie'
                 }];
                 Plotly.newPlot(elem[0], data)
            };
        });
    }
}
```

#### USAGE:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="i in datafile.items">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>Total MB: {{i.total_mb}}</p>
        <p>Used MB: {{i.used_mb}}</p>
        <p>Free MB: {{i.free_mb}}</p>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="myDiv{{$index}}" plotly="i"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, tried that and that does not work :(. Anything appears on the page

Comment: Is the `postLink` function being invoked? Is the `$watch` function being invoked? What is the value of `i` when invoked?